# Rounding corners on a html5 textbox which uses a placeholder

Tags: html, rounded-corners, placeholder

Hi Im creating a login form which uses the html5 placeholder.

```
<form name="login" id="LoginForm" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

I have also used css3 border-radius:6px;. However when I click ont he textbox even though the corners are rounded the highlight around the textbox still has corners. Does anyone know a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the `outline`

```
input {
    outline: 0;
}
```

However this is a very important accessibility feature, so it's a good practice to provide alternative styling on focus (e.g. give it a background, change text color etc.)

Comment: +1, Remember that colorblind can't always detect certain color changes (eg: red, green)  Change light and dark (or bold) if you want color to have meaning.

Comment: Thank you this worked. To replace it i'll try to do a border when the user clicks on it